# How can i disable dojox.mobile.IconMenuItem icon

Tags: dojox.mobile

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenu" id="menu"
            style="width: 100%; height: 210px; margin: 20px; background-color: white;"
            data-dojo-props="cols: 2">
            <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenuItem" id="iconDisable"
                data-dojo-props="label: 'Item',icon:'images/thumbnail.png',moveTo:'Enview0',disabled:'true'"></li>
            <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenuItem"
                data-dojo-props="label: 'Item',icon:'images/thumbnail.png'"></li>``
</ul>
```

I need to disable one icon in this.i have tried disabled:true but i didn't worked for me.Please anyone help me

Thanks